ArcadeDb studio when starting embedded server
I created a simpple springboot app and I am using arcadeDb as embedded server. The app starts up fine and I am able to save the save the data. However, when I try and access the arcade studio on "http://localhost:2480", I get message - "Not found".
This is what I have in my gradle file
implementation com.aracdedb:arcade-engine:$A_VERSION
implementation com.aracdedb:arcade-server:$A_VERSION 

Here's my ArcadeDB config
@Configuration
public class ArcadeDbConfig{
  
  @Bean public ServerDatabase getDb(){
  Contextconfiguration config = new ContextConfiguration();
  config.setValue(GlobalConfiguration.SERVER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY, "/da/aracde/myDb");
  ArcadeDbServer server = new ArcadeDbServer(config);
  server.start();
  
  ....
}
}

Am I missing any dependencies? I also tried adding configuratio "SERVER_MODE, development" but that too did not enable the studio in embedded mode.

Include the arcadedb-studio-{{version}}.jar in your dependencies. The studio web tool is released in a separate jar.

Thanks Lvca. I will update the documentation.

Found few more things missing in the document. Ex: Gremlin langauge available after you add the arcade-studio. I had to look in code and found that to enable gremlin, you have to do things: 1. Add "arcadedb-gremlin" and 2. In the the ContextConfiguration you need to add this property - config.setValue(GlobalConfiguration.GREMLIN_ENGINE, "groovy") . Note: The code says auto sets it to Groovy but I added "auto" instead of "groovy" or "java", I was getting error that gremlin is not recognized

@DineshArora it would be awesome if you can open an issue with it, or contribute to the docs ;-)

Created the PR - https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-docs/pull/264
